# hiding a div in web-browser Windows phone with javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, html, windows-phone-8

I am trying to hide some `div`s on a webpage within Windows Phone 8.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="topbar_container">...</div>
    <div id="banners">...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the C#:

```
private void Browser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Browser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementsByClassName('topbar_container')[0].style.display = 'none';");
    //this works

    Browser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementsById('banners')[0].style.display = 'none'");
    //This dont work
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second `InvokeScript`, you've mistakenly invoked a function called `document.getElementsById`. It should be:

```
document.getElementById
```

(Not plural `"Elements"`).